# Sorting of centralized logs with journalctl (journald)

Tags: linux, logging

I'm running an environment with multiple hosts that all are sending their logfiles to one central loghost using journald (systemd-journal-remote). On the central loghost, an aggregated view can be show using the -m (-merge) option which according to the manpage does "show entries interleaved from all available journals, including remote ones": `journalctl -m` .

1. The problem is that this output is sorted by hostname and then by date instead of by date in the first place. Is it possible to generate an output with the date as the first sort criteria?
2. Why does `journalctl -mf` only show log entries from one of the hosts?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why this question got downvoted, but here's my workaround:

`journalctl -m --since "10 minutes ago" --no-pager -o short-unix | sort -n | awk -F" " '{OFS=" "; $1=strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", $1); print $0}'`